# How to group VALUES of same KEY of map in a List<Map<String,String>> in JAVA?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, hashmap, set

I have a List of Map in which there are many similar keys.
So i want to group the values of the same keys as a `List<Map<String,List<String>>>`

Note :- **here the keys of the map are unknown**

```
Input - 
List<Map<String,String>> list = [{CLEANING=cleaning1}, {CLEANING=cleaning2}, {CLEANING=cleaning3}, {CLEANING=cleaning4}, {PAPER=paper1}, {PAPER=paper2}, {PAPER=paper3}, {PAPER=paper4}]

Output - 
List<Map<String,List<String>>> outputList = [{CLEANING,[cleaning1,cleaning2,cleaning3,cleaning4]},{PAPER,[paper1,paper2,paper3,paper4]}]
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service. What have you tried already, and what problems did you encounter?

Comment: Sometimes, inputs look strange, because they came from some programs. It's understandable. However, in your output, what is the purpose of the outer `List` ? A map can contain more than one key

Comment: yes... any ways you can try @Kent

Comment: @MrFreak any ways **I** can try?

Comment: yes brother @Kent

Comment: @MrFreak hum... any ways... I would pick this way: how about I post a question at SO and let someone do it for me...

Comment: Have a look at [`Collectors.groupingBy`](https://www.baeldung.com/java-groupingby-collector)

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<String,List<String>>
```

Check if key exists then append to string else add key and assign it a list with that string.
Is you want your list to be just use a set instead.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why do you need single entry maps in a list but it looks like the better structure as the result would be just a `Map<String, List<String>>`.

Here is a code that you could use using streams.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Map<String, String>> list = List.of(
        Map.of("CLEANING", "1"),
        Map.of("CLEANING", "2"),
        Map.of("PAPER", "1")
    );

    List<Map<String, List<String>>> result1 = list.stream()
        .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
        .collect(groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, toList())))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .map(e -> Map.of(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
        .collect(toList());

    Map<String, List<String>> result2 = list.stream()
        .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
        .collect(groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, toList())));

    System.out.println(result1); // [{CLEANING=[1, 2]}, {PAPER=[1]}]
    System.out.println(result2); // {CLEANING=[1, 2], PAPER=[1]}
}
```